# Send UIButton touch event to didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I have a UIButton added to a UITableViewCell

In order to reduce code redundancy, I'd like to touch event of UIButton to fall through the cell - so it ends up in:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Can you tell me how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a bad idea. Instead, you should call the same function from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` & the button's action method & place your common code in that function. Something like-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//fetch the cell corresponding to this index path
MyCustomCell* cell = (MyCustomCell*)[self cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] ;
[cell foo] ; 


}

-(void) buttonClicked:(id)sender //In your custom cell class
{
    [self foo];
}
```

HTH,

Akshay

Comment: hey... but my cell is a custom cell view, that is why i jsut want to propagate it up to the table cell. they don't reside on the same class.

Answer (score 8):

In your button's action method, you can determine the index path of the row from the table view and pass that to the delegate method:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)button
{
    CGPoint point = [button center];
    UITableView *table = [self tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [table indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
    [[table delegate] tableView:table didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Comment: it would be easier - similar to above, if only my button code is in the same class as where my tableview is. my button code is on its own custom UITabelViewCell.

Comment: Your `-buttonClicked:` method should be defined in a class that has access to the table view.  The button action should not be handled by the cell.  Instead, the button should be a public property of your `UITableViewCell` subclass, so that `tableView:CellForRowAtIndexPath:` can call `-addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` on the button.

Comment: Note: if you did put that button into a UIView (inside the tablecell, if you want to make it scroll for instance), you should use `convertPoint:toView` method